# How to disable the back button after Session has destroyed?

Tags: asp.net, session

I want that after Logging Out any user should not be able to go to the Back Page.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Clear the cache instead, it's more reliable.

Add these to your header section of the page :

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
```

And add this to your page load :

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Comment: Similar to this, add a no-cache header to the output of your pages that you don't want the user going back to.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can not disable back button of web browser.

Add the following

"if user is logged in"

```
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" %>
<% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %>
<% Response.Expires = -1 %>
```

Comment: Suppose i am in a page and i have clicked the logout Button, then it is taking me to Login Page.
But if i am Clicking the Back button then it is Displaying me the previous page and its value .
How to stop that ?

Comment: as answered by Canavar, clear cache. Add no cache header. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting no-cache on the pages viewed by authenticated users, that should requier the users browser to reload the page from the server.

Comment: Clicking the Back Button it is not doing a PageLoad. So how to do anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the back button is not possible, perfectly. So you can:

1. Close the window on Log off.
2. On each page, check for a valid session and if not found, redirect to login page.

Comment: 1. bad solution
2. will not work for back button as browser does not does a post back on back button.

Comment: @rats. you are mostly right, but in my experience, safari makes a fresh request on back

Comment: i am not sure about safari, but IE, FF and Opera does not do a post back unless you ask them not to cache. :-)